# How to configure fallback value of constant if multiple #[cfg(...)] don't match?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

I am trying to set value of constant based on `target_os`. I want to achieve something like this:

```
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
const MAP_FLAGS: libc::c_int = libc::MAP_POPULATE;

#[cfg(target_os = "macos")]
const MAP_FLAGS: libc::c_int = libc::MAP_NOCACHE;

#[cfg(/* ELSE */)]
const MAP_FLAGS: libc::c_int = 0;
```

Now, natural idea is to use `cfg!` macro, but that won't compile because `libc::MAP_POPULATE` is present only on linux targets and `libc::MAP_NOCACHE` is present only on macos targets.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're very close. If you want a default just for anything that's not linux or macos, you can combine `not()` with `any()`:

```rust
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
const MAP_FLAGS: libc::c_int = libc::MAP_POPULATE;

#[cfg(target_os = "macos")]
const MAP_FLAGS: libc::c_int = libc::MAP_NOCACHE;

#[cfg(not(any(target_os = "macos", target_os = "linux")))]
const MAP_FLAGS: libc::c_int = 0;
```

Comment: This is silly... :-) So, there is no equivalent of C's #ifndef, right?

Comment: The only alternative is `cfg_if` as @Locke suggested.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you may want to try using the [`cfg-if`](https://crates.io/crates/cfg-if) crate. It provides a macro (`cfg_if`) that allows for conditional compilation in an if-else structure.

```rust
cfg_if::cfg_if! {
    if #[cfg(target_os = "linux")] {
        const MAP_FLAGS: libc::c_int = libc::MAP_POPULATE;
    } else if #[cfg(target_os = "macos")] {
        const MAP_FLAGS: libc::c_int = libc::MAP_NOCACHE;
    } else {
        const MAP_FLAGS: libc::c_int = 0;
    }
}
```

That being said, this is just syntactic sugar for `#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]`, `#[cfg(all(target_os = "macos", not(target_os = "linux")))]`, and `#[cfg(all(not(target_os = "macos"), not(target_os = "linux")))]`.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Frankly, I hesitated to choose which answer to accept, so at least upvote for you.